# Ubuntu screensize

Tags: 16.04, display, display-resolution

I have an Asus pc with a 13 inch screen.
I have installed ubuntu but having troubles with the resolution. Some things appear very small. I can't seem to find a way to fix it. I added a screenshot to show my problem. You see my filesystem,that looks okay. And also two programs in a really small window with incredibly small font. Is there a way to fix this.[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01V6y.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem exactly is, but you can activate "Large Text" in the Universal Access settings of ubuntu.

`Systemsettings -> Universal Access -> Seeing -> enable Large Text`

That would make all your text larger for easier to read text.

Comment: This does not solve my problem, it is only in some programs the font is very small.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these -  I had the opposite problem on an eeepc;
[X Config Resolution](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution)
also this 
[Ubuntu Geek xrandr](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-change-display-resolution-settings-using-xrandr.html)

Comment: I don't know about those things, I don't want to change everything, it is just some programs that show in a minuscule window with even smaller text font. One of them is python gui maker. And changing text fonts doesn't help for that window.